# Different Designs and Different screen sizes and Densities

Tags: android, android-layout

I have read an much more documents on android and other blogs about how to support multiple screen sizes. And To some extent I am successful in making some good looking designs for apps. Now let me start from the start what is the problem and what I wanted to ask from you guys.

Android has now different screen sizes of different screen densities and having different resolutions. so We have to face 3 different things the size , density and the resolution.

Now Let take example of Samsung s4(xxhdpi device having 1080*1920px) , Samsung Grand (hdpi 480*800px) and both has same screen size that is 5 inch 
and Samsung galaxy note 10.1 (Mdpi devices ) 10 inch screen size.

Now android says to make different drawable and put them into respective folder, its ok, let suppose its done. Now what ?

lets suppose , What if I have to set the image in left top with the marginleft of 5 dp and some other views according to them with different specific paddings and margins in dps and suppose I have set all of these in my layout according to hdpi device, which we know is not going to look good in  samsung s4 xxhdpi device and tablet.

and Also as design pattern says to change design for the tablets according to your need , but on the other hand the support of making different layout has been deprecated now we have to use different values folder.

so in short what is a best way and what is clear thing for making drawables. 
how should we re size our drawables to support all devices , and also if making different layout has been deprecated now what should we do to make our design look good and approximately same in all devices?

also how to judge that device is tablet and we should now start showing the multi pane design ?

please do not refer me to android developer website , I know its very helping and I learnt a lot from there , but right now I just want to discuss the technical issues and want to take advantage of some experienced developers. Thanks